# C# validate phone number with Regex

Tags: c#, regex

It would be great if someone could help me with a Regex for phone numbers.
I have one TextBox and I use the C# Control "RegularExpressionValidator" to validate it.

```
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPhone"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" 
       ErrorMessage="Pleace enter valid phone number " 
       ControlToValidate="txtPhone"
       ValidationExpression="">
 </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

The TextBox text have to allow only to be entered this kind of phone numbers

ex: +934 888 555 22 13

Can someone help me for the Regex?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Visit [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Comment: Is it that format only? Are there any variations of it that are permitted?

Comment: No, other formats are not allowed, only this one

Comment: Is that ALL cases? What about without spaces? How about the plus-sign, is that necessary? Are you doing anything to help the users type it in, in that format?

Comment: Yes, there is a hint how it should be written.
Spaces are allowed,and the plus-sign must be there.